# :last-of-type Or :nth-of-type(n) Where n Is Last Element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This question concerns conventions for using `:nth-of-type(n)` where `n` is the last element or `:last-of-type`.  By definition, there is no difference between the two provided `n` is the last element, so in theory either should work.  Here is some generic example code (this obviously isn't the real code, but something this simple suffices as a demonstration):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style type="text/css">
div:first-of-type { background-color: red; }
div:last-of-type { background-color: green; } /* or div:nth-of-type(n) for last element n*/ 
</style>
<html>
<div>Row 1</div>
<div>Row 2</div>
</html>
```

What is the typical convention in a scenario with a known amount of elements?  What if there are just two elements? In both cases, which pseudo-selector is typically used?

Additionally, what about an unusual scenario where a coder only has control over the stylesheet and the HTML is extremely unlikely to but technically liable to changing?  Or does this all fall to personal preference in both cases.

Comment: If there's ever a possibility of there being more than two of these items, choose based on whether you need to style the last one or the second one.

Comment: As a side note, if you have control over the code I would suggest giving each of your divs a class and style them that way. Using `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` in the way you posted above would easily break if you were to ever modify your html.

Comment: You've got a lot of questions in your post. Posts with a single targeted question are generally preferred...

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: It's not too bad - the questions are all very closely related and can be answered in a couple of paragraphs. If the asker hadn't enumerated the different scenarios they wanted answered, then, ironically, the question would be too broad.

Comment: @CWSites: Using class names isn't going to magically make the CSS robust to changes to the HTML. It really depends on *how* the HTML is changed. If you append additional elements after the element with the "last" class name, then you'd have to reassign that class name, when using a pseudo-class would have made that unnecessary...

Comment: @BoltClock, I wasn't suggesting that changing the class was some magical cure all. I was suggesting that in this particular case using `first-of-type` and `last-of-type` would break as soon as another `div` was added. A problem with using a pseudo-class is that if someone else comes to edit the HTML they have no idea that styles are being applied. At least with my suggestion they would see the presence of a class and investigate.

Comment: @CWSites: If the :last-of-type styles transfer to the new last element, then the CSS is working as intended and nothing is being broken. If the CSS author didn't intend for the styles to transfer this way then they shouldn't have used the :last-of-type pseudo in the first place (as I touched on in my answer). If the layout itself doesn't support adding new elements this way, then that's a limitation of the layout that isn't going to be mitigated by using classes over pseudos. The HTML editor needs to communicate with the CSS editor either way.

Comment: This question as it stands is honestly one that invites an opinion-based response. BoltClock's answer is good, but addresses this question as it *ought* to be asked, not as it *currently exists*. I would urge you to edit this (as I feel it's your prerogative to do so) to ask this question in a non-opinion-based way, e.g. "what is the actual difference between selecting things these two ways". QED, I don't think Shog's reopening was justified WRT to the state of the question as it was when that happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is largely a matter of semantics.

Generally, you use `:first-child/:first-of-type` and `:last-child/:last-of-type` when you're interested in styling the first and last element (only, or differently from other nth elements over competing `:nth-of-type()` rules) and you want these rules to apply to the first and last even when the number of elements can vary.

Even if you do know the number of elements in advance, and even if this number will never change, `:nth-of-type(X)` where X is the number of elements doesn't make it immediately clear that it's referring to "whichever element is the last" and not some arbitrary Xth element:

```css
div:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: yellow; }
div:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: red; }
div:nth-of-type(12) { background-color: green; }
```

This, of course, is highly subjective — you may know your layout intimately enough that you know there will always be exactly X elements, so the example above will always target the first and last, and you may be the only developer to ever see your code and so it's not going to matter to you. That's why I said it's a matter of semantics. (You could get away with using `:nth-last-of-type(1)`... but then you might as well save yourself the keystrokes and use `:last-of-type` instead.)

The only situation in which `:nth-of-type(X)` would be preferable is if you plan to extend this with additional `:nth-of-type()` rules, each styling a specific element differently from the first two:

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) { background-color: red; }
div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: green; }

/* Added */
div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: blue; }
```

In other words, when you want the rule that applies to the second element (the "last") to continue applying to the second element even when a third element is added — and you don't want that rule to then apply to the third (the new "last") element when that happens — use `:nth-of-type(2)`, even if for example only 2 elements appear in the layout *by default*. At this point, you are no longer dealing with first/last semantics, but you are (and have all along been) dealing with nth semantics.

In such a situation, it might seem unnecessary to then use `:nth-of-type(1)` over `:first-of-type`, since the first element will *always* be the first no matter how many elements you add or remove from your layout. Which one you use in that case is indeed down to personal preference — for example, I would prefer `:nth-of-type(1)` for consistency with the other rules so it doesn't look like the odd one out:

```css
div:first-of-type { background-color: red; }    /* Looks out of place... */
div:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: green; } /* ... when every other element... */
div:nth-of-type(3) { background-color: blue; }  /* ... is numbered */
```

> Additionally, what about an unusual scenario where a coder only has control over the stylesheet and the HTML is extremely unlikely to but technically liable to changing?

That's not all that unusual actually. If the HTML is extremely unlikely to change, then it's likely that the layout doesn't support it and is therefore not going to continue to work correctly if it *does* change. Whether you use first/last or nth isn't going to make much of a difference, so my advice of choosing based on semantics remains.

---

For the sake of completeness, there is one additional catch when it comes to `:first-child`: unlike `:last-child`, `:only-child`, `:nth-child()`, and *all* of the type-based variants (`:*-of-type`), `:first-child` was introduced in CSS2 and therefore several very old browsers only support that without supporting any of the rest.

In this day and age you probably don't have to worry about this, but if you *did* want your layout to gracefully degrade on very old browsers, you might consider using `:nth-child(1)` so that it fails on unsupported browsers along with all the other `:nth-child()` rules, rather than having the first element styled and the rest not, which depending on your layout might look ugly at best or cause adverse layout problems at worst.

Answer (score 1):

Last type would ideally be used when you're unaware of the value of n

for example highlight the last list item red

```
li:last-of-type
{
   background: red;
}
```

if you know the value if n for your specific scenario then you would use the nth type 
for example you always wanted to highlight the second list item blue you would use

```
li:nth-child(2)
{
   background: blue;
}
```