# what is the difference between :nth-child(1) versus :first-child in css pseudo selectors are there any merits in choosing one method over the other?

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
p:nth-child(1) {
color: red;
}

p:first-child {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>first</p>
<p>second</p>
</div>
```

which pseudo selectors is best to apply color in the paragraph tag in the code

Comment: What's `sass` got to do with this?

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/54539822/8620333

Comment: Historically, there were some browsers that supported `first-child` before they supported `nth-child()`, but it's not a practical issue today.

Answer (score 8):

Both will match the same elements. No difference in a page: same specificity, same behavior.

`:first-child` is easier to understand for a human and is a nice addition for us humans to the generic `:nth-child(an+b)`

`nth-child(1)` is easier to be written programatically/generated. No need to add a condition in your preprocessor code to test "if it's equal to 1 than output selector `:first-child` or else output `:nth-child(your variable)`".
It also obviously has to exist as well as any other arbitrary value 2, 213, whatever.

edit: fwiw `:first-letter` and `:first-line` already existed prior to these pseudo-classes, it'd have been strange/annoying not to have `:first-child` when `:nth-child(an+b)` was created :)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same, it does the same job, however `:nth-child` gives you more room to experience.

For example

```
@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .element:nth-child(#{$i}n) {
    animation-delay: #{$i * 0.05}s;
  }
}
```

You could iterate and then dinamically use it to select childrens.
Of course you will need a preprocessor to do this (`SASS`)